# CreateProcess succeeds, but GetLastError() returns access denied

Tags: c++, access-denied, createprocess, getlasterror

I'm having a little confusion due to conflicting return values from `CreateProcess()` and `GetLastError()`. When I use `CreateProcess()` in a manner similar to below, it succeeds and appears to accomplish its required tasks. Yet, `GetLastError()` still returns Access is Denied.

If access is denied, why is does it appear to complete the task. In contrast, if `CreateProcess()` succeeds, why is `GetLastError()` returning access denied?

Or is my use of `GetLastError()` incorrect? Am I only supposed to use it when `CreateProcess()` returns a failed value? (My justification for the below behavior was that I figured it was better to be safe than sorry)

```
    SetLastError(0);
    hello = CreateProcess(_T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"), 
        _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C ant debug"),
        NULL,NULL,false,0,NULL,
        _T("C:\\My\\Directory"),&siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo);
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER 
        |FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,NULL,GetLastError(), 
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
        (LPTSTR)&errorText, 0, NULL); 
    AfxMessageBox(errorText);
```

Is this type of behavior normal? In the `CreateProcess()` documentation, it mentions using `GetLastError()` when `CreateProcess()` fails, but it does not mention the inverse. Not criticizing the documentation, would just like some clarification.

This occurs whether the second parameter in `CreateProcess()` is `NULL` or not. Maybe it has to do with `cmd.exe` permissions? If that's the case, shouldn't `CreateProcess()` fail? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, your use of `GetLastError` is incorrect. You should only use it when `CreateProcess` fails. `CreateProcess` may (and does) use APIs that can set the last error, and it's not obligated to reset it to 0 since it returns a value indicating success.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was only resetting it to zero to show that it could not be from a function before CreateProcess()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `GetLastError`

> The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function sets the last-error code. Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. However, **some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed**. [emphasis mine]

I think you get the experienced outcome because, uppon success, `CreateProcess` does not set the error value `GetLastError` returns.  Instead your call to `GetLastError` returns an error set by another function called earlier

Comment: Thank you. If I `SetLastError(0)` immediately before my call to CreateProcess, shouldn't it return 0 rather than 5?

Comment: @JHowzer - it depends on how `CreateProcess` is implemented.  If it calls other functions, those could set the error value as well

Answer (score 1):

`GetLastError` is only meaningful when the documentation states it is meaningful.

`GetLastError` returns the Win32 thread last error set with `SetLastError`. Since functions are only supposed to set or clear the last error when it is documented that they do so, if that hasn't happened, the last error may well contain an earlier error which is not relevant.

It is documented that `CreateProcess` will set the last error if it fails, not if it succeeds. So you should ignore it.